# Subset in different data frames based on a column with the same level name

Tags: r

guys!
I hope you could help on this:

I have a long dataset that I need to subset in several data frames based on a group of variables to later spread them across colums. Here is my code for a replicable example

```
Variable<-c("Population for whom poverty status is determined", "AGE", "Under 18 years", "Related children under 18 years", "18 to 64 years", "65 years and over", "SEX", "Male", "Female", "RACE AND HISPANIC OR LATINO ORIGIN", "One race", "White", "Black or African American", "American Indian and Alaska Native", "Asian", "Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander", "Some other race", "Two or more races", "Hispanic or Latino origin (of any race)", "White alone, not Hispanic or Latino", "EDUCATIONAL ATTAINMENT", "Population 25 years and over", "Less than high school graduate", "High school graduate (includes equivalency)", "Some college, associate's degree", "Bachelor's degree or higher", "EMPLOYMENT STATUS", "Civilian labor force 16 years and over", "Employed", "Male", "Female", "Unemployed", "Male", "Female", "WORK EXPERIENCE", "Population 16 years and over", "Worked full-time, year-round in the past 12 months", "Worked part-time or part-year in the past 12 months", "Did not work", "All Individuals below:", "50 percent of poverty level", "125 percent of poverty level", "150 percent of poverty level", "185 percent of poverty level", "200 percent of poverty level", "Unrelated individuals for whom poverty status is determined", "Male", "Female", "Mean income deficit for unrelated individuals (dollars)", "Worked full-time, year-round in the past 12 months", "Worked less than full-time, year-round in the past 12 months", "Did not work", "PERCENT IMPUTED")
Year<-rep(2010,each=53)
County<-rep("San Diego", each=53)
State<-rep("California", each=53)
Total<-sample(1:100, 53, replace=TRUE)
Below_poverty_level<-sample(1:100, 53, replace=TRUE)
Percent_below_poverty_level<-sample(1:100, 53, replace=TRUE)

poverty<-data.frame(Variable, Year, County, State, Total,Below_poverty_level, Percent_below_poverty_level )
```

This is how I need it:

Group educational attainment levels alone

```
newdata <- poverty[ which(poverty$Variable=='Population 25 years and over'|poverty$Variable=='Less than high school graduate' |poverty$Variable=="High school graduate (includes equivalency)" | poverty$Variable=="Some college, associate's degree"|poverty$Variable=="Bachelor's degree or higher" ), ]
```

Transform the data as needed:

```
edu<-newdata %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(Variable:State)) %>% 
  unite(temp, Variable, variable) %>%
  spread(temp, value)
```

So I can save it as:

```
library("writexl")
write_xlsx(df,"A:\\Data Repository clean\\2. Social Indicators\\Poverty\\Poverty by educational att 2010-2021.xlsx")
```

The problem comes when I need to extract a piece of totally different information that is under "Female" and "Male" level but in different categories: SEX, EMPLOYMENT STATUS.

In the code, based on the "Variable" column above here I the categories and all the rows below those categories (see list):

Population for whom poverty status is determined

AGE

SEX

RACE AND HISPANIC OR LATINO ORIGIN

EMPLOYMENT STATUS

Employed

Unemployed

WORK EXPERIENCE

All Individuals below:

Unrelated individuals for whom poverty status is determined

are the ones I need to extract.

So, as muy may see, "Female" and "Male" is labeled the same for SEX, EMPLOYMENT STATUS  Unemployed, EMPLOYMENT STATUS Employed. And I need the distinction.

I'd like to know how to either rename those specific levels, attach the category label, etc., or to find a way to subset it without mixing up the information.
(Maybe subset all information below SEX two times, or attache SEX.Female, SEX.Male, etc)
I have the same information for 2010-2021 and for several Counties and States, so a manual relabelling is not an option

I appreciate your help!

In case the code is too messy: https://rpubs.com/AleidaRamirez/836753